# How do I add significance asterisks next to my values in a correlation matrix heat map?

Tags: heatmap, correlation, significance

I found this code online at http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization

It provides instructions for how to create a correlation matrix heat map and it works well. However, I was wondering how to get little stars * next to the values in the matrix that are significant. How would I go about doing that. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
mydata <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
head(mydata)
cormat <- round(cor(mydata),2)
head(cormat)
library(reshape2)
melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)
head(melted_cormat)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile()
# Get lower triangle of the correlation matrix
  get_lower_tri<-function(cormat){
    cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- NA
    return(cormat)
  }
  # Get upper triangle of the correlation matrix
  get_upper_tri <- function(cormat){
    cormat[lower.tri(cormat)]<- NA
    return(cormat)
  }
upper_tri <- get_upper_tri(cormat)
# Melt the correlation matrix
library(reshape2)
melted_cormat <- melt(upper_tri, na.rm = TRUE)
# Heatmap
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value))+
 geom_tile(color = "white")+
 scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", 
   midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", 
   name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
  theme_minimal()+ 
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
    size = 12, hjust = 1))+
 coord_fixed()
reorder_cormat <- function(cormat){
# Use correlation between variables as distance
dd <- as.dist((1-cormat)/2)
hc <- hclust(dd)
cormat <-cormat[hc$order, hc$order]
}
# Reorder the correlation matrix
cormat <- reorder_cormat(cormat)
upper_tri <- get_upper_tri(cormat)
# Melt the correlation matrix
melted_cormat <- melt(upper_tri, na.rm = TRUE)
# Create a ggheatmap
ggheatmap <- ggplot(melted_cormat, aes(Var2, Var1, fill = value))+
 geom_tile(color = "white")+
 scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white", 
   midpoint = 0, limit = c(-1,1), space = "Lab", 
    name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
  theme_minimal()+ # minimal theme
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, 
    size = 12, hjust = 1))+
 coord_fixed()
# Print the heatmap
print(ggheatmap)
ggheatmap + 
geom_text(aes(Var2, Var1, label = value), color = "black", size = 4) +
theme(
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.border = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
  legend.justification = c(1, 0),
  legend.position = c(0.6, 0.7),
  legend.direction = "horizontal")+
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 7, barheight = 1,
                title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`cor()` doesn't show the significance level, you may have to use `rcorr()` from `Hmisc` package

This is quite similar to what you want (the graphic output is not so nice though)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(Hmisc)
library(stats)

abbreviateSTR <- function(value, prefix){  # format string more concisely
  lst = c()
  for (item in value) {
    if (is.nan(item) || is.na(item)) { # if item is NaN return empty string
      lst <- c(lst, '')
      next
    }
    item <- round(item, 2) # round to two digits
    if (item == 0) { # if rounding results in 0 clarify
      item = '<.01'
    }
    item <- as.character(item)
    item <- sub("(^[0])+", "", item)    # remove leading 0: 0.05 -> .05
    item <- sub("(^-[0])+", "-", item)  # remove leading -0: -0.05 -> -.05
    lst <- c(lst, paste(prefix, item, sep = ""))
  }
  return(lst)
}

d <- mtcars

cormatrix = rcorr(as.matrix(d), type='spearman')
cordata = melt(cormatrix$r)
cordata$labelr = abbreviateSTR(melt(cormatrix$r)$value, 'r')
cordata$labelP = abbreviateSTR(melt(cormatrix$P)$value, 'P')
cordata$label = paste(cordata$labelr, "\n", 
                      cordata$labelP, sep = "")
cordata$strike = ""
cordata$strike[cormatrix$P > 0.05] = "X"

txtsize <- par('din')[2] / 2
ggplot(cordata, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=TRUE)) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  geom_text(label=cordata$label, size=txtsize) + 
  geom_text(label=cordata$strike, size=txtsize * 4, color="red", alpha=0.4)
```

[Source](http://proven-inconclusive.com/blog/spearman_correlation_heat_map_with_correlation_coefficient_and_significance_in_r.html)

Answer (score 0):

difference_p is the P_value of correlation matrix,
ax5 draws the sns.heatmap and return as ax5

```
data=correlation_p
for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        if data[y,x]<0.1:
            ax4.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '-',size=48,
                 horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center',
                 )
```

[image]